# Keyboard shortcut to split screen in half with source pane on left and console pane

Tags: r, rstudio

Is there a keyboard shortcut that splits the RStudio window in half with the source on the left and console on right (and hides all other panes) as per screenshot below?

[image]

Comment: There are currently no exported commands, see [this list](https://docs.rstudio.com/ide/server-pro/rstudio_ide_commands/rstudio_ide_commands.html) that cover all the individual actions needed to make a shortcut. One approach could be to programmatically click the `GONVA-ECHR GONVA-ECAR rstudio_panel_max_btn_source` button (inspect element in Rstudio), followed by `rstudioapi::executeCommand("maximizeConsole")`, wrapped in a function and added as a new shortcut. I failed to implement it - but perhaps it might help others in finding an answer!

Comment: This is blatantly off-topic. You're asking a question about the aesthetics of an IDE and not about programming. This question belongs on RStudio forum (https://community.rstudio.com/) not on SO.

Comment: The aesthetics of RStudio exerts a strong influence on programming. I did try on RStudio forum some weeks back but got no replies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following might do the trick:

Set up your own shortcut for `Maximize Console`

1. Go to Tools -> Modify Keyboard Shortcuts
2. Filter: Search for Maximize Console
3. Under Shortcut add your own shortcut such as `Ctrl C M` for Console Maximize

Keep left side for Source ONLY (if you think that it OK).

1. Go to Preferences (`Command  ,`)
2. Go to Pane Layout and **deselect all** in the lower-left corner

The History panel that you had to deselct from the Source side you can add  to the lower-right panel; and then open it using `control 4`. And you can do the same for the Help panel, which you open using `Control 3`

Comment: It sort of works. But RStudio still randomly feels the need to show the bottom left pane every now and then, even though there is nothing in that pane. It also randomly decides that it will dedicate one third of the screen to the source pane and the other two thirds to the console, instead of a 50/50 split. Not sure why more people do not seem to have an issue with this.

Comment: sorry to hear about the erratic behaviour, personally I have not noticed this for the "empty" bottom panel, nor that the vertical split changes automatically (Im on Mac OS, RStudio Version 1.4.1717) – out of interest, what do you use?

Comment: I'm on Mac RStudio 2021.09.1+372. The change to one third left panel and two thirds right panel happens after going to View > Panes > Show All Panes. The bottom left pane also maximises after pressing View > Panes > Zoom Source.

Comment: Oh I see – good that you've identified when it happens so it's not at random :)

The View > Panes > Show All Panes also produces the one third left panel for me – but in my workflow I get around this. I go to panes using Ctrl + [Number] (different number give different panes). And if you press Ctrl + shift + [Number] it maximizes that pane. So, *if you press Ctrl + shift + 3 twice it shows you all panes without producing the one third-effect.* (not optimal: weird). 

The bottom left pane does not maximise when I use View > Panes > Zoom Source – so perhaps try updating RStudio.

Comment: Pressing Ctrl + shift + 3 does get rid of the one/third effect. But it has frustrating side effect of maximising either the bottom left pane (despite it being blank) or the bottom right pane. It's frustrating enough to make me want to go back to using TextMate + R app like I used to.

Comment: This is strange – something I don't have; according to Rstudio release notes this bugg should have been fixed. "Fixed issue where empty panes would remain open and pop open unexpectedly (#8460)" https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/release-notes/ 

Are you maybe using custom fonts? It appears to have been associated with causing similar problems...

Comment: Using monaco font - don't think that's a custom fault is it? Also using latest version of RStudio.

Answer (score 2):

There is no shortcut that will arrange the panels properly. However, you can save their layout! Whenever you need it, you can load any panel layout. The layout of the panels is saved in the rstudio-prefs.json file which is located (in the case of Windows) in C:\Users\UserName\ AppData\Roaming\RStudio where, of course, **UserName** is the name of the current user. You only need to save this file once when RStudio has your favorite panel layout and then you copy it where you want to quickly recall it.

I checked it and it works for me without any problems. Unfortunately, changing the layout of the panels will only work after restarting RStudio.

Comment: Is this the same as going to RStudio Preferences > Pane Layout?

Comment: Yes. The settings that you change by clicking the Tools\Global Options...\Pane Layout menu or the View\Panes\Pane Layout... menu are saved in this file. Just replace it and restart RStudio and the panels layout will change to the same as it will be saved in the rstudio-prefs.json file.